# preg_replace arrays with multiple patterns per replacement

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I don't think I can do this in one *swell foop*, but I'm not above asking :-)

I can certainly define one-to-one `$pattern` and `$replacement` arrays, and I can repeatedly define `$pattern` arrays and `$replacement` strings, but can I do both at once?

Suppose I have three sets like:

```
$p1 = array('sis','boom','bah');
$r1 = 'cheers';

$p2 = array('boo','hiss');
$r2 = 'jeers';

$p3 = array('guinness','heineken','budweiser');
$r3 = 'beers';
```

and I'd like to replace in a single large haystack all instances of patterns with their respective single replacements.  Is there a single `preg_replace` call that I can define to accomplish this?

Comment: you can use `(sis|boom|bah)` in your pattern if you're using regular expressions, otherwise str_replace can take an array of values for the search and replace with a single value.

Comment: `str_replace()` will not respect word boundaries and may return unexpected results when a substring is found inside another substring.

Comment: To fully expose the trouble with not including word boundaries... if you have `$string='My sister paid 500 baht for a boomerang';` and use `echo preg_replace('/sis|boom|bah/','cheers',$string);` then you will get this mangled mess: `My cheerster paid 500 cheerst for a cheerserang` while there were no intended replacements to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to incorporate word boundaries with a regex-based function.

Consider this `strtr()` demo:

```
$string="Rah rah, sis boom bah, I read a book on budweiser";
$p1 = array('sis','boom','bah');
$r1 = 'cheers';
$p2 = array('boo','hiss');
$r2 = 'jeers' ;
$p3 = array('guinness','heineken','budweiser');
$r3 = 'beers';

$replacements=array_merge(
    array_combine($p1,array_fill(0,sizeof($p1),$r1)),
    array_combine($p2,array_fill(0,sizeof($p2),$r2)),
    array_combine($p3,array_fill(0,sizeof($p3),$r3))
);
echo strtr($string,$replacements);
```

Output:

```
Rah rah, cheers cheers cheers, I read a jeersk on beers
//                                      ^^^^^ Oops
```

---

You will just need to implode your `needle` elements using pipes and wrap them in a non-capturing group so that the word boundaries apply to all substrings, like this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99836be12d6572a2d95e575d4e9389ab75e032de))

```
$string="Rah rah, sis boom bah, I read a book on budweiser";
$p1 = ['sis','boom','bah'];
$r1 = 'cheers';
$p2 = ['boo','hiss'];
$r2 = 'jeers' ;
$p3 = ['guinness','heineken','budweiser'];
$r3 = 'beers';
$find=['/\b(?:'.implode('|',$p1).')\b/','/\b(?:'.implode('|',$p2).')\b/','/\b(?:'.implode('|',$p3).')\b/'];
$swap=[$r1,$r2,$r3];
var_export($find);
echo "\n";
var_export($swap);
echo "\n";
echo preg_replace($find,$swap,$string);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '/\\b(?:sis|boom|bah)\\b/',                 // unescaped: /\b(?:sis|boom|bah)\b/
  1 => '/\\b(?:boo|hiss)\\b/',                     // unescaped: /\b(?:boo|hiss)\b/
  2 => '/\\b(?:guinness|heineken|budweiser)\\b/',  // unescaped: /\b(?:guinness|heineken|budweiser)\b/
)
array (
  0 => 'cheers',
  1 => 'jeers',
  2 => 'beers',
)
Rah rah, cheers cheers cheers, I read a book on beers
```

*Notes:

The word boundaries `\b` ensure that whole words are match, avoiding unintended mismatches.

If you need case-insensitivity, just use the `i` flag at the end of each regex pattern.  e.g. `/\b(?:sis|boom|bah)\b/i`

Comment: Aha!  
Yes, changing each array of patterns to a single regexp would reduce it to 1:1 again.  That's a bit of a pain, but implode() is a cool trick that makes this programmatic again. 
I'll look forward to more ideas, but this probably gets the check mark when I can look again tomorrow :-) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = 'sis + boo + guinness';
echo preg_replace(['/sis|boom|bah/','/boo|hiss/','/guinness|heineken|budweiser/'],['cheers','jeers','beers'],$subject);
// the result would be cheers + jeers + beers
```

> replacement
>   The string or an array with strings to replace. If this parameter is a
>   string and the pattern parameter is an array, all patterns will be
>   replaced by that string. If both pattern and replacement parameters
>   are arrays, each pattern will be replaced by the replacement
>   counterpart. If there are fewer elements in the replacement array than
>   in the pattern array, any extra patterns will be replaced by an empty
>   string.
>   ...
>
> If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on
>   every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well.

Comment: Your method yields an unintended result when `boo` is changed to `book`.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4cbf8093df5dee1dfba98c98017d68948af1b57  See my answer regarding word boundaries.

Comment: @mickmackusa, in the link above `$subject = 'sis + book + guinness';` resulted in `cheers + jeersk + beers` which is the normal expected behaviour,

Comment: Not if you only want to replace the whole word `boo` instead of the start of `book`  See what I mean?